# Using train stations in other editions

Tags: ticket-to-ride

Can you use the train stations from the European edition with any other editions?.  Like with London or Pennsylvania.

Answer (score 1):

I own or have played all versions of Ticket To Ride.

Ticket To Ride - Europe is the only version that I know of that uses stations.

As a house rule, there is nothing that will prevent you from using the stations with the other versions but you will then not be playing according to the official rules.

Comment: Do you have any insight as to how the presence of stations will affect the other versions?

Comment: I think the stations were introduced into TTR Europe because the map is so tight and too many games would see players abandoning routes that they couldn't complete, a depressing finish for a game. Adding stations to other more open versions would probably shorten the game dramatically because it would prevent blocking.

Comment: Stations might work out when you have 1 fewer or 1 more player than needed for double routes.